# Fit divs next to each other if they exceed the size of the body;

Tags: css

Is there a way to fit two divs next to each other with CSS when they both have width:75% of the body? They always stand one over the other since there is no space for both. Here is a JSbin http://jsbin.com/eGAgOjit/1/

Note: do not change the width from 75%!

Comment: what you want to do is not very clear you should detail more the current behavior and your expectation. As I see here you have div id="positions" and all your element are on one line the there is enough place.

Comment: So you want the body to eventually become "150%" width?

Comment: @Passerby I do not know yet I am trying stuff around if I come with a solution I will post it. There is one and that is sure. I have already rotated the navigation with  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); and it is ok but now I cannot move it to the left of the body.

Comment: @HenryLynx Two 75% box stand next to each other, what else would you mean other than "150% width in total"? What is your expected behavior?